# How to Merge two pptx files having charts and tables using java api?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx4j

I have tried merging two pptx files through java API (Apache POI)
It worked for PPTX having only text Content.

I need help to merge two PPTX files without losing charts, tables, images, Themes etc. Are there any open source java API-s for this?

Comment: Currently POI ignores charts, so if you decide to use POI you would need to  implement the copying yourself, i.e. you have low-level access to the chart/themes xmls and also need to handle the relationships

Answer (score 0):

**Disclosure: I work for Plutext**

Plutext's Docx4j Enterprise Edition can merge complex presentations.  You decide whether the output takes on the look of the first pptx, or retains the individual look/feel of the inputs.  As simple usage is like so:

```
    String[] deck = {"deck1.pptx", "deck2.pptx"};               

    PresentationBuilder builder = new PresentationBuilder();            
    builder.setThemeTreatment(ThemeTreatment.RESPECT); // preserve appearance of each deck?

    for (int i=0 ; i< deck.length; i++) {

        // Create a SlideRange representing the slides in this pptx
        SlideRange sr = new SlideRange(
                (PresentationMLPackage)OpcPackage.load(
                                        new File(DIR_IN + deck[i])));

        // Add the slide range to the output
        builder.addSlideRange(sr);

    }

    builder.getResult().save(
            new File("OUT_MergeWholePresentations.pptx"));
```

Docx4j Enterprise Ed is a commercial product.  I'm not aware of an open source solution which offers what you want via a high level API. As with POI, you could implement what you want yourself using open source docx4j/pptx4j's low level API, but to do so you'd need a decent understanding of the pptx file format and pptx4j.  (docx4j/pptx4j use JAXB; POI uses XML Beans)